# How to skip to next line if condition is not met?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, readline, skip

The code does something with a line in a text file (that part works - thanks to your help). But if a condition is not met in that line (if it does not contain the word "Intron" or the word "Exon") it should skip to the next line and repeat the action.

```
dataFile = open('test.txt', 'r')
wordexon = "Exon"
wornintron = "Intron"
for eachLine in dataFile:
    if wordexon or wordintron in Line:
            tmpStr = ' '
            for char in eachLine:
                tmpStr += char
            s = tmpStr.split()
            print '\t'.join((s[0], s[3], s[4]))
    else next(iter)
```

Comment: I don't understand the `next(iter)` part. Does it run? How can you `next` the builtin function `iter`?

Comment: Can't? :) OP would get a `TypeError` with that code.

Comment: Found it somewhere else, had no idea it doesn't run :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the

```
else next(iter)
```

That will do.

That said, you could have written your code like this:

```
for eachLine in dataFile:
    if not ((wordexon in Line) or (wordintron in Line)):
        continue
    tmpStr = ' '
    for char in eachLine:
        tmpStr += char
    s = tmpStr.split()
    print '\t'.join((s[0], s[3], s[4]))
```

Also, your condition is wrong. It will always enter the `if` as it is.

Comment: Just in case you need an explanation: Python's `for` is a "for each" structure. It will automatically iterate over the contents of the object you place after `in` (`dataFile`, in your case), so there's no need to be explicit, asking Python to iterate (and you can't either). You can use the familiar (to C-like programmers) `break` and `continue` inside a loop, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Either remove next(iter)
2. or use `continue` to make your intent clear.

   ```
           s = tmpStr.split()
           print '\t'.join((s[0], s[3], s[4]))
   else:
           continue
   ```